# Device encryption and broken screen

Tags: security, encryption, touchscreen, broken-screen

Assuming you have a device that is encrypted by the factory encryption option in the security settings of the device, and having said device suffer a fall and end up with a broken screen, what are the options to recover your data (if any)

Comment: Getting the screen replaced, probably. Standard procedure.

Comment: Nothing you can do on your own, correct?

Comment: Very probably there's nothing you can do else. It's by far the safest way to do it (if not the only one). Depending on the device, it may be possible to dump the partition and access the crypto key but this is only possible if the device has an unlocked bootloader and if the crypto key is also on disk (and not in a locked TPM). E.g. it's not possible on Google Nexus devices (they wipe the storage when you unlock the bootloader). You could also only temporarily connect a working display unit from another spare device, search ifixit.com for teardown howtos to learn how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what kicks in when, but might it be possible to attach some external devices: monitor via HDMI, keyboard/mouse via OTG, and "work around the broken screen" that way – or would that be impossible as support for OTG/HDMI only becomes available after having entered the encryption key/password?